# Inserting into database from textbox in C# using parameters

Tags: c#, sql

I am a newbie to c#. I am trying to insert the values from the text box into the table in my database.

Table Name : address

Fields : name(varchar(50)),
         age(int),
         city(nchar(10))

When i try to retrieve the values from the database it is working perfectly.
Here is my code. Please help me rectify it.

```
            string s = @"Data      Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated  Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection a = new SqlConnection(s);

            a.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [address](name,age,city)  VALUES(@na,@ag,@ci)");
            string na = textBox1.Text;
            int ag = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            string ci = textBox3.Text;

            comm.Parameters.Add("@na", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = na;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@ag", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int).Value = ag;
            comm.Parameters.Add("@ci", System.Data.SqlDbType.NChar,10).Value = ci;
            comm.Connection = a;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("okay");
            a.Close();
```

The values are not reflected in the database.

Comment: Of the top of my head, I'm going to throw out there that it's a file system permissions problem since he's attaching a SQLExpress file.  Just a wild guess, but let's see if it holds up. =)

Comment: @AustinSalonen am not getting any error but the values are not reflected in the database.

Comment: comm.Parameters.Add("@na", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = na;
you might want to try to put a closing bracket.
comm.Parameters.Add("@na", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = na);

Comment: Jane: that would make two closing brackets.

Comment: @JaneDoe How can i add a closing bracket without an opening one.

Comment: trying throwing a break point just after SqlCommand comm and see what the sql statement in comm actually shows.  the take that and run it against the sql file itself and see if it inserts or throws an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with this code :

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated  Security=True;User Instance=True";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

    using (SqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand())

        {
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO address(name,age,city) VALUES (@na,@ag,@ci)";
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@na", na);
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ag", ag);
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ci", ci);


            insertCommand.Connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you closing the SqlConnection inside a `using`?

Comment: using call dispose in the end of treatment

Comment: It is working now. The inserted data is present in the database, but the table in Database explorer is not updated. I am getting the new values when i use the select query i did. And may i know why is the table not getting updated?

Comment: you must just refresh your table in your explorator

Comment: Yeah tried that it aint working. One more thing the data is just available temporarily. When i close the solution and open it again, the newly inserted rows are gone. Is there something like PERSIST that we got to do?

Comment: what?? i dont understand. What am i to do now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13069/discussion-between-dnivra-and-aghilas-yakoub)

Comment: try not copy in the property panel of your mdf database (properties Visual studio).